# How to use JavaScript with gwt Uibinder

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, uibinder

I want to execute JavaScript in my application which is written with GWT.
This is the code that works in a regular HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.roundabout.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('ul').roundabout();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Assume `jquery.js` and `jquery.roundabout.js` are in the same folder.)

I have a `somePresenter` (with `someView.java` and `someView.ui.xml`) and I want the above code to work in the `someView.ui.xml`.

I copy pasted the above code to the XML (except for `<html>` tag I have `<g:HTMLPanel>` tag)
but the JavaScript doesn't seem to be executed (all I see is the list as it should be before the script).

How can I make it work?

Related question: can I some how use GQuery for this 
(something like: GQuery.$().getScript(jquery.roundabout.js) to load external js script)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put jQuery and plugin scripts in your host page? With proper caching configured it will not impact your application performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't put a `<script>` in UiBinder and expect to see it loaded and executed for the same reasons you cannot put a `<script>` in a `innerHTML` in JS with the same expactations (simply because `HTMLPanel` and UiBinder will use `innerHTML` under-the-hood).

If you need to load scripts dynamically, have a look at  the [`ScriptInjector`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html):

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + 'jquery.js').inject();
```

I suppose GQuery uses `ScriptInjector` or works similarly.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to do this by putting the

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.roundabout.js"></script>
```

in the `project.html`
and then executing the relevant JavaScript with JSNI call when the relevant page loaded (my presenter).