# How to open/collapse GWT Bootstrap Accordion programmatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gwt, accordion

Can anyone please mention how to open/collapse bootstrap accordion programmatically.
This is my uibinder xml for ACCORDION widget. I want to collapse it my uibinder java class.

```
<b:Accordion>
<b:AccordionGroup heading="COMPARE" ui:field="compareAccordion">
    .
    .
    .
</b:AccordionGroup>                     
</b:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this, my accordions would lock up after calling hide() or show(). I found I had to put the hide() and show()'s in a deferred command:

```
void expandAndCollapseGroups(final Collection<AccordionGroup> expand,
        final Collection<AccordionGroup> collapse) {
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            for (AccordionGroup accordionGroup : expand) {
                accordionGroup.show();
            }
            for (AccordionGroup accordionGroup : collapse) {
                accordionGroup.hide();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, take a look here:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

```
$(".collapse").collapse();
```

For how to use that Javascript code in GWT, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178034/how-to-use-javascript-with-gwt-uibinder) and the link to [ScriptInjector](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html) mentioned in it..

Edit: Did some research, you should check your markup to make sure you're really using the collapsibles mentioned in that Twitter Bootstrap link above. If not, try the [Collapse class](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/gwt-bootstrap/apidocs/com/github/gwtbootstrap/client/ui/Collapse.html).

Answer (score 0):

`compareAccordion.show()` to open and `compareAccordion.hide()` to collapse should work.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
$('#collapse_id').collapse('show');
```

And works fine, does exactly the same as clicking on:

```
<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_id">
  Collapsible Group Item #1
</button>
```

I used it in a group of collapsible divs (accordion), and it behaves normally (opening one 
will close the recently opened one)